# Does VPN protect against ESET SSL protocol filtering?

Tags: vpn, ssl

I read this article(linked below) which explains that ESET installs new root certificate authority and decrypts all your secure traffic. I wondered if VPN protects against this or not?

https://device5.co.uk/blog/do-not-use-eset-ssl-protocol-filtering.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the anti-virus scanner is running on your local PC, a VPN does not change anything. It only protects your data on the network.

This type of scanning usually works by injecting a DLL into target processes that will then redirect traffic to a proxy the AV scanner is running.

Normal traffic route (with VPN): Browser → VPN (→ external network)
AV scanner traffic route (even with VPN): Browser → AV scanner → VPN (→ external network)

A VPN can never protect data on your local machine. If the local machine has been compromised (by a badly-designed virus scanner or whatever), nothing will help you.